# Integrating Grid into Page object model

Tags: java, selenium, grid

I currently run my tests from my local machine, I now want to run my tests from with Jenkins using selenium grid.

Currently my set up project set up is as follows:

```
public BasePage(WebDriver driver){

    this.driver = driver;
    jsExecutor = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver);
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 200);
}

public void loadPage(){

    driver.get(getPageUrl());
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
```

These methods are inherited by

```
 CretePage.java

public CreateClass(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
        this.PAGE_URL = "http://xxxxxx.12121/home";
    }


public void createClass(String name){
    openPage();
    findDynamicElement(By.id("id"), 12);
    clickElement(button_Save);
}
```

Then my test runs for the class `RunTest.java`

```
public WebDriver driver;
    public WebDriverWait wait;
    CreateLocation CreateLocation;


    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setup(){
        this.driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

        CreatePage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, CreatePage.class );

@Test(priority=1)
public void createClass(){
    CreateClass.createClass("Selenium Webdriver Class");

}
```

Any code changes I have made so far has resulted in build failures or empty browsers been launched. Can anyone explain what I should try do or an article to read to help me with this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have your hub and one or more nodes set up and running, you'll need to use the RemoteWebDriver and DesiredCapabilities class. This should all be done in the setUp(). Something like this:

```
@BeforeClass
public void setUp() {
    String baseUrl = "http://www.google.com"; // Wherever you start your test
    String nodeUrl = "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"; // Whatever the URL is to your hub
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capabilities.setBrowserName("firefox");
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeUrl), capabilities);
    driver.get(baseUrl);
}
```

I found most of this info on [Selenium's GitHub page](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2).

Comment: I've tried this it does not work with my current code shown above. It only opens a second empty browser. Where exactly should I put this in the code I have provided?

Comment: Node and hubs run fine when I use a basic selenium script. It is trying to create a framework that uses Project Object model & selenium grid I get runtime problems.

Comment: What is the runtime error you are getting? Please add it to your original post.